# Table View cell image with specific size

Tags: ios, xcode, tableview, cell

I have a TableView that load images from my Url, everything's fine. The problem is when I scroll down or up, the images become bigger in the cells. Sometime it become bigger than the cell it's self.

I have tried every thing, but it is not working, I am sitting the View mode to Aspect fit, but still have the same problem.

Her is my code:

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
CellView *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (!cell) {
cell = [[CellView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}

ListOfObjects *listObjects;

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
listObjects = [listArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.userName.text = userName;


ListOfObjects *venue = ((ListOfObjects * )self.listArray[indexPath.row]);
NSString *one = listObjects.theUserId;
NSURL *myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:one];

if (listObjects.image) {
cell.imageView.image = listObjects.image;
} else {
// set default user image while image is being downloaded
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"second58.png"];

// download the image asynchronously
[self downloadImageWithURL:myUrl completionBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, UIImage *image) {
if (succeeded) {
// change the image in the cell

cell.imageView.image = image;

// cache the image for use later (when scrolling up)
venue.image = image;
}
}];
}
```

Can any one give me an idea about it?

Comment: Add the code where the logic is there

Comment: Can you post pics of the problem? What do you mean they are bigger than the cell? Do they appear zoomed in or are the overflowing the view. Check the contentView on the cell size and then check heightForRow as well as the width of the tableView itself to see if it works for your images

Comment: The images are overflowing the Cells, Unfortunately I can't post image because I am new user. Lets say the original image frame size (40*40), after loading the table from my url and scroll down the image become bigger, lets say (100*100)

Comment: Her is a link of a photo, shows what is the problem alomee.com/khadamati/myImage.png

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can resize image frame:

```
[self downloadImageWithURL:myUrl completionBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, UIImage *image) {
if (succeeded) {
cell.imageView.image = image;
cell.imageView.frame = your.frame;
}
}];
```

if you cache the image, you should set it's frame when you use it, not only when it finished download

Comment: Still have the same problem! as soon as I scroll down the image become bigger.

Comment: is your cell dealloc'ing and a generic cell alloc'ing in it's place?

Comment: Her is a link of a photo, shows what is the problem http://alomee.com/khadamati/myImage.png

Comment: if you cache the image, you should set it's frame when you use it, not only when it finished download